# High chart is not getting populated

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I am totally new in highchart,I started learning and I am trying to display simple pie chart in html but its is not working . everything looks ok to me,I dont know what is wrong. highchart is not getting populated.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DrunkenCooder/L5gutrv7/6/)

```html
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Final</title>
  <!--Bootstrap source start-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--Bootstrap source end-->
  
  <!--highchart source start-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="C:\Users\Global Soft\Desktop\HighChart\js\highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--highchart source end--> 
  
  
  <!--Charts starts here-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function (){
   var charti;
   $(document).ready(function(){
    charti=new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart:{
                        renderTo:'pie',
      plotBackgroundColor:null,
      plotBorderWidth:null,
      plotShadow:false  
     },
     
     title:{
      text:'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
     },
     
     subtitle:{
      text: ' Pie Chart'
     },
     tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
     },
     plotOptions: {
      pie: {
       allowPointSelect: true,  
       cursor: 'pointer',
       dataLabels: {
        enabled: false  
        
       },
       showInLegend: true
      }
     },
     
     series:[{
      type:'pie',
      name:'Browser share',
      data:[
       ['Firefox',45.0],
       ['IE',26.8],
       {
        name:'Chrome',
        y:12.8,
        sliced:true,
        selected:true
       },
       ['Safari', 8.5],
       ['Opera', 6.2],
       ['Others',  0.7]
      ]
          
     }]
    
     
   });
   
  }); 
 });
   

 </head>
 
 <body>
  
  <div class="container">
   <h1 align="center"><a href ="#">Different charts in one page</a></h1>
   <!--First chart-->
     <div class="col-md-6">  
      <div id="pie" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 30 auto"></div>  
     </div>
   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your path to Highcharts is wrong. Open JavaScript console (web developer tools) and check errors. And jsFiddle doesn't work because you didn't include Highcharts and jQuery.

Comment: I agree but in my html code I have included highchart, though its not working

Comment: Check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e1v1kq1m/ I think this is what you are looking for. I just updated yours.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if u got the path right to the highchart. I added this and it worked fine

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry but its really not working, Ihave download the highchart and given the right path. but still its not working can please make it more clear

Comment: When I am including this into my code, I am getting file not found eror in console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined
exporting.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of undefined
highcharts.js:13 Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
exporting.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of undefined

Comment: remove your includes and add the mentioned includes and it should work. I dont know why u are getting this error.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I was missing closed </script> tag and the library problem was there.